# I have wrong header height when I'm logget Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header

I have my own wordpres template where I have a header consisting of two parts and how scrolling the header is scraping up and leaving only the menu..the problem is that when i'm crawled in WordPress the header height is different than when i'm not logged in and i do not know what is cause That's why somebody had a similar case? I need help and I will be grateful for any tips.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tamjp.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked that the admin-menu is not interfering with the rest of the layout of the page? Because that layout-wise on a standard installation would be the only difference between beeing logged in or not.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the header in h1 tag and than:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 40;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Header<h1>
```